# How do you solve "sum of ages" puzzles?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

> Ma and Pa and brother and me. The sum of our ages is eighty-three. Six
>   times Pa’s age is seven times Ma’s age, and Ma’s age is three times my
>   age.

What is Pa’s age? What is Ma’s age? What is my brother’s age? What is my age?

I try setting up the first equation in four variables letting $A$ be ma's age, $B$ be pa's age, $C$ be my brother's age and $D$ be my age.

$$A+B+C+D=83$$

The problem gives

\begin{align}
7B&=6A\\
A&=3D
\end{align}

but I am still lost observing the fact that there was not any fact on my brother.

Comment: [Maybe because you're twins](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SOLVE+M%2BP%2BB%2BY%3D83%2C+6P%3D7M%2C+M%3D3Y%2C+B%3DY&x=0&y=0)

Comment: This question has been reposted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003302/find-the-ages-of-three-people-given-their-sum-and-two-relations-between-the-age

Answer (score 3):

If Pa’s age $=7a,$ Ma’s age $=6a,$ your age$=2a$

If your brother’s age $=b,$  we have $7a+6a+2a+b=83\iff b=83-15a$

If ages are integers, $a\le5$

If $a=5,b=8$

If $a=4,b=23$ and Ma’s age $=6a=24$ which is impossible

Comment: [Wolfram alpha says](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SOLVE+M%2BP%2BB%2BY%3D83%2C+6P%3D7M%2C+M%3D3Y+OVER+INTEGERS&x=0&y=0)

Comment: @Digital Brain seems legit

Comment: I really don't get

'which is impossible'

Comment: @DigitalBrain, What's the minimum age difference a mother & her child :)  $b$ is the brother's age, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee OP didn't mentioned anything about 'Humans'

Answer (score 0):

You got the first equation backwards.  It should be $6B=7A$.  (That is, six times Pa's age, which you've called $B$, is seven times Ma's age, which you've called $A$.)  So we have

$$\begin{align}
A+B+C+D&=83\\
6B&=7A\\
A&=3D\\
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?  (Hint:  Ages are typically positive *whole* numbers, and parents should be a good deal older than their children.)

Comment: this was what i got and i got stock after i came up with an equation that had two variables i still need help

Comment: @Acade, does lab bhattacharjee's answer make more sense?  You are quite right that, as a pure math problem, three linear equations are not enough to specify four unknowns, but as a "puzzle" problem, we can bring some additional common sense to it.