# Find the ages of three people, given their sum and two relations between the ages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> Solve this riddle:
>
> “Ma and Pa and brother and me
>   The sum of our ages is eighty-three
>   Six times Pa’s age is seven times Ma’s age
>   And Ma’s age is three times my age.”
>
> What is Pa’s age? What is Ma’s age? What is my brother’s age? What is my age?

I try by setting up three equations from the problem 
$$A+B+C+D=83$$ where I took $A$ to be Ma's age, $B$ to be Pa's age, $C$ to be my brother's age and $D$ to be my age.

I then came up with two other equations $6B=7A$ and $A=3D$. I later solve these and came up with $15D+2C=166$ but I am lost and need help.

Comment: If you want line breaks, you need to double-space your lines: otherwise, the formatter thinks you were just writing one big paragraph and reformats it that way.

Comment: For future reference, the word `I` is always capitalized in English. The first letter of the first word of each sentence is also capitalized.

Comment: so can i get my help please

Comment: This is a reposting of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002561/how-do-you-solve-sum-of-ages-puzzles

Answer (score 3):

- $P$ Pa
- $M$ Ma
- $B$ Brother
- $Y$ You

$$P + M + B + Y = 83$$
$$6P = 7M$$
$$M = 3Y$$

Combine and write everything in terms of $B$ and $Y$.

$$21/6 Y + 3Y + B + Y = 83$$
$$45 Y + 6B = 498$$

Sum of even numbers is even, so $Y$ must be even, call it $Y=2n$:

$$90n + 6Y = 498$$
$$15n + Y = 83$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} n \\ 83 - 15n \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} Y \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2n \\ 83 - 15n \end{bmatrix}$$

Insert back in the parents:

$$\begin{bmatrix} P \\ M \\ Y \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 7n \\ 6n \\ 2n \\ 83 - 15n \end{bmatrix}$$

I think we can assume $B \ge 0$, so $83 - 15n \ge 0$, so $n \le 5$.

Hopefully $B < M$, so $83 - 15n < 6n$, so $n \ge 4$.

So your choices are $n=4$ or $n=5$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} P \\ M \\ Y \\ B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 28 \\ 24 \\ 8 \\ 23 \end{bmatrix} \text{ or } \begin{bmatrix} 35 \\ 30 \\ 10 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

Assuming you are humans and your brother isn't adopted, it's probably the second one.

Answer (score 0):

From$$15D+2C=166$$You can conclude that $D$ must be a multiple of $2$ and its maximum value would be when $C=1$ which means max $D=10$.

So then try and see what values you get for $A,B,C$ when $D=2,4,6,8,10$.

Only one of these combinations will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$6B=7A$ means that $B$ is a multiple of $7.$ Say, $B=7x.$ Now, it is $7A=6B=42x\implies A=6x.$ Since $6x=A=3D$ we have $D=2x.$ Thus,

$$A+B+C+D=6x+7x+C+2x=15x+C=83,$$ or equivalently $$15x=83-C.$$ The LHS is a multiple of $15$ (that is, $15,30,45,60$ or $75$). So, $C=8,23,38,53,68$ or $83.$ Since $C\le A$ and $C\le B$ it is $3C\le 83,$ that is,  $C=8$ or $C=23.$

If $C=23$ then $x=4$ and $A=24, B=28$ and $D=8.$  If $C=8$ then $x=5$ and $A=30, B=35$ and $D=10.$ The first solution doesn't make sense because the difference between the age of the father and the son is one year. So $A=30, B=35,$ $C=8$ and $D=10.$